# Show a list of the latest commits in my current branch

Tags: git

Is there a way to get a list of all commits after the commit I am checked out currently?
For example in this image, I'm on commit 84a90... [Commit History in Sourcetree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHmYE.png)

and in my terminal, I want to see a list of the next 3 commits, preferably with the commit comment & the changed files.

Comment: If you are using "detached HEAD" mode to view a commit that's not a branch-tip commit, you're not "on" a branch, and hence there is no current branch name. If you know what the branch name is, though, the syntax `HEAD..<name>` selects the commits you want. j6t's answer can then be modified to use `git log --name-status <branch> ^HEAD` or `git log --name-status HEAD..<branch>`.

Comment: Let's vote to close this question. User is not replying/clarifying anything.

Answer (score 0):

Git can only walk from any commit *specified* to older commits. To see commits younger than some other commit, you have to specify other commits, too, from which Git can walk backwards. For example:

```
git log --name-status --all ^HEAD   # or --not HEAD
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @rafathasan: it *does* answer the question; the problem here is that the question itself is not very good, and this is the only possible answer. You've answered a *different* question, which might be the one the OP meant to ask.

Answer (score -1):

`git log --name-status` is one option. Is there anything specific that is missing from the output of this command that you want to see?

Comment: This shows the current commit and all older commits, I want the latest commits

Comment: You will see the commits from your checked out version and older.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question not even close.

Answer (score -1):

You can view the list of commits in formatted form --

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h -%an, %ai : %s"
```

Comment: This is good but it doesn't show the changed files of the commit but very useful anyways thank you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can see the last 3 commits using the below commands

```
git show -3
```

Comment: This one also shows the current commit and all older commits, I want the latest commits

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

This should suffice

```
git log --oneline --name-status @..80200a0
```

Here's a sample of my (apparently useless) answer:

```
$ git rev-parse @
3e6990fffa8aa82d9fea5ced8148a7fc4d33a8b1
$ git checkout @~3 # let's get ourselves 3 commits behind 3e6990fffa
Note: switching to '@~3'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make .
.
.
$ git log --oneline --name-status @..3e6990fffa8aa82d9fea5ced8148a7fc4d33a8b1
3e6990f (master) Something else
M       hello.txt
3f3461a Both files
M       hello.txt
A       hello_world.txt
f4f73f6 adios
M       hello.txt
```

Comment: now.... who deleted all the _prose_ that had been written as comments over here?

Answer (score -2):

Your question is a bit tricky other people misunderstood. But I know what you are looking for. Lets say you checkout on a previous commit and you want see latest commits ahead of the previous commit.

```
 git log --branches --oneline ...
```

This will only show all the commits ahead of `head`.

Expected Output:

```
b452743 (tag: v0.1.2-beta, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) update: close driver at the end
a150370 fix: remove spaces from header line
cb7d6f5 (tag: v0.1.1-beta) chore: remove folder from gitignore
968db4f add: example directory file
ab65070 (tag: v0.1.0-beta) Update README.md
ddfa102 Update README.md
20a3308 Update README.md
7500552 Update requirements
```

This will only show commits done after `HEAD` commit.

If you want to view including old commits:

```
git log --branches --oneline
```

Expected Output:

```
b452743 (tag: v0.1.2-beta, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) update: close driver at the end
a150370 fix: remove spaces from header line
cb7d6f5 (tag: v0.1.1-beta) chore: remove folder from gitignore
968db4f add: example directory file
ab65070 (tag: v0.1.0-beta) Update README.md
ddfa102 Update README.md
20a3308 Update README.md
7500552 Update requirements
44220ff Fix argument passing in Listerner
05e7697 Fix remove unused config
726bea0 (HEAD) Fix #1
9ad4e4c Add webdriver, no longer need to download chromedriver
03bfc94 Update README.md
82cb75f Update README.md
b0d10d0 Update README.md
54f55c4 Create README.md
3f57df5 add requirements
88d5276 add README
eb29696 update gitignore
56a06ad update key listerner
df2398e update main.py
35fb259 update .gitignore
0e615f3 add utils
142314c add utils
6a548b7 add config
378ff5e add .gitignore
12c372d add placeholder main.py
```

Comment: This one is the closest to what I want, is there a way to only check the future commits ( only commits that come after the one I'm on )?

Comment: `git log --branches --oneline ...` will only show the latest commits. Check the answer it has been edited.